# Resize Image File On React before uploading to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I need to resize image before uploading to firebase.

The approach I took and that did not work caused I used a package

> import Compressing from 'react-image-file-resizer';

Which converts file either to base64 or blob

after uploading Image won't show up it looks like this

[image: Here is the image]

> Type application/octet-stream

Here is the code below

```
const onChangeHandler = async (event) => {
   
    const imageFile = event.target.files[0];

   let imageUri
        Compressing.imageFileResizer(
      imageFile, // the file from input
      480, // width
      480, // height
      'png', // compress format WEBP, JPEG, PNG
      70, // quality
      0, // rotation
      (uri) => {
        // Your upload logic goes here
  
        imageUri = uri.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, '');
   
      },
      'base64' // blob or base64 default base64
    );

     const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${imageFile.name}`).put(imageUri)
     uploadTask.on('state_changed',(snapshot)=>{
        //progress funtion.....
     }, (error)=>{
       //error function
         console.log(error)
     },()=>{
         //complete function
         storage.ref('images').child(imageFile.name).getDownloadURL().then(url=>{
           console.log(url,'--------------------------')
         })
     })
```

Comment: @Kundan Are you sure that answer applies to this question? (it's a great answer either way). The OP Here is asking how to resize *before* uploading. The accepted answer in that question resizes it *after* uploading.

Comment: OP, that screen shot is showing a .png file. What do you mean by *after uploading Image won't show up*. Also, can you clarify what the issue is? Is it how to compress an image (which is not related to firebase) or how to upload an image (which is related to firebase)?

Comment: @Jay It is showing .png but image is not rendering because it says Type application/octet-stream.  I have tried clarifying all things above if I send image file  `const imageFile = event.target.files[0];` directly to firebase image renders. but I used package to compress Image file which manuplates `const imageFile = event.target.files[0];` to blob or base64 which then send to firebase .png shows up but image won' t render. Now I am asking is there anyway to compress image before sending to firebase or can blob or base64 file can be send to firebase and converted back to image that can render

Comment: What's being asked is still unclear; if there's a .png image and it's compressed/scaled/edited on the device and saved as a .png image it can then be uploaded to Firebase Storage like any other .png image file. It's not clear what blob or base64 has to do with uploading an image to Storage in this case as conversions to another type are not necessary; File types are fully supported. Please see the documentation [Upload Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_files) as it shows how to upload a .jpg - a .png works the same way.

Comment: Also, ensure the the passed parameters here `storage.ref(`images/${imageFile.name}`).put(imageUri)` are valid - it's not really clear what those parameters evaluate to.

Comment: @ranjan if you have solved it please share your code, it could help me and others too